# Securing stunnel.pem on Windows

Tags: windows-xp, stunnel

How can I prevent reading of the stunnel.pem file by any user other than the service user running Stunnel? How can I permit access to this directory (C:\Program Files\stunnel) in Windows XP to only the Stunnel service?

Comment: Are you on a domain?

Comment: @Mark: Nope. No domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safest way to do this is to create a user account specifically for the stunnel service, and then apply the permissions appropriately

1. Start > Run > `lusrmgr.msc`
2. Right-click users and choose `New user...`
3. Enter in the user details, and [generate a strong password](http://www.pctools.com/guides/password/) for the account (you'll only need it for the new few minutes, so just keep it in notepad for the time being).
4. Start > Run > `services.msc`
5. Right-click the stunnel service and go to properties
6. Go to the Log On tab and check the option for `This Account`
7. Enter the username and password from Step 3
8. Click OK and you should get a message about the account being granted "Logon as a service" right
9. Go to the security properties of `C:\Program Files\stunnel\` and apply `Full Control` to the user from Step 3
10. Remove excess permissions from the folder (you might need to go to Advanced and un-check Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent)

Done!